# Sum Columns from joined tables to get a calculated value using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

[image: Relationship Diagram]

In the above diagram for each customer I want to select all orders and then for each order I have calculate a TotalPrice = (Sum of all Food Items included in order * Quantity) + ExtraPrice. I am struggling to create a query for it using linq to sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var res = (from a in dc.orders
                   join b in dc.orderLines on a.orderId equals b.fk_orderId
                   join c in dc.foodItems on b.fk_foodId equals c.foodId
                   where a.fk_custId == cID
                   group new { a,c,b } by a into g
                   select new 
                   {
                       OID1 = g.Key.orderId,
                       date1 = g.Key.date.Value.Date,
                       price1 = g.Sum(x => x.c.price * x.b.quantity) + g.Key.orderLines.Select(o => o.extraPrice).Sum()
                   });
```

Given above is linq query I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something close to this. I'm not around a computer to test so let me know if you get errors.

```
db.orders.Select(o => new { o.orderid, o.date, TotalPrice = ( (o.orderLines.Select(ol => ol.food items.Count()).Sum() * o.Quantity) + o.extraPrice) } )
```

Comment: It shows error at ol.foodItems.Count(). Doesnot contain a definition for count.

Comment: and I have to also specify a where clause for customer id.

Comment: dc.orders.Select(o => new { o.orderId, o.date, TotalPrice = ( (o.orderLines.Select(ol => ol.foodItem.price).Sum() * decimal.Parse(o.orderLines.Select(ox => ox.quantity).ToString())) + decimal.Parse(o.orderLines.Select(x => x.extraPrice).ToString())) } );

Tried this and it throws exception. Cannot translate.

Comment: I can't test that right now but I guess it has to do with `decimal.Parse()` which might not have a T-SQL equivalent. May I ask why you are ToStringing it and then parsing it back to a `decimal`? If you remove that you might find it behaves as expected.